# rsyslog property replacer regex requires double escape to use special characters?

Tags: regex, rsyslog

Consider the following log line:

`2019-04-20 21:17:57,505341,+0000 [Web,279,10.0.0.100] c4da4857-63b1-11a9-a00a-b0521699037b TCP RX ...`

I want to strip the timestamp `2019-04-20 21:17:57,505341,+0000` at the beginning before writing this log line with rsyslog.

I've leveraged the property replacer in a template using a regex to match everything after the timestamp as so:

`template (name="mylog" type="string" string="%timereported% %syslogtag% %pri-text% %msg:R,ERE,1,BLANK:(\\[.*)--end%\n")`

Notice the double `\\` before the bracket `[`.

If I only use a single `\` before the bracket rsyslog throws an error but works just fine with the double `\\`

I'm not very experienced with regex but my understanding is that a special character like the bracket `[` requires a single `\` to be escaped so that it can match the literal bracket in the log line. Why is it that a single `\` doesn't work in rsyslog but double `\\` does?

I'm using rsyslog v8.40.0 on Debian.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the regex syntax, but you must remember you are providing it as a string constant, so you must also respect the [rules](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/rainerscript/constant_strings.html) for these which state that special characters (including backslash) are escaped with a backslash. The linked-to page has a link to an [online tool](https://www.rsyslog.com/rainerscript-constant-string-escaper/) to do the escaping for you.